# Sending auth cookie to android app from an external wordpress api?

Tags: android, wordpress, api, cookies

I Have an android app that connects to wordpress with an api that i wrote .

My login and Registration works fine ,

**But when i login the user from android 
app i want to have an auth cookie to use it in a webview in android app .**

***HOW CAN I GET THAT COOKIE ? AND HOW TO SET IT IN ANDROID APP ?***

and i read alot about it , and not found Anything ...

i read about wp_set_auth_cookie() and another wordpress functions ...

any suggestion will be usefull , thanks ...

Comment: Have you tried this? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_parse_auth_cookie 
You could retrieve the auth cookie that way and provide an endpoint in the api, where the android app can ask for that cookie

Comment: thank you but  i just want to login a user and get a cookie ? and this function looks like parse a cookie ...

Comment: you wanna log in a user on android?

Comment: You should probably create a custom login route in the WP that will return the auth cookie details in the response. You can then use it in your app.